Ubuntu (FAILED) messages on startup, even after reinstalling from USB (Framework laptop)
I am running Ubuntu on a Framework laptop.  I was on 22.04 and was having difficulties with video freezing (with audio still continuing) - can't recall how far I had got with trying to update/upgrade when I stated to get lots of (FAILED) [in red] messages on startup, and the machine wouldn't start up.
I made a 24.04 usb and upgraded to Noble Numbat (keeping my data from before but with the OS (presumably) on a separate drive - I had to navigate to a different home directory to get at my data).
After a short time (less than a week) I started to get 'short of space' messages, and then (FAILED) messages on startup again, and the machine won't boot up normally.
I have now backed up all of my data, so I can start completely afresh - but I am a bit of a novice, so would appreciate clear and explicit instructions!
Many thanks in anticipation!
